# What is the best to have URL like thumbnail indicating the location like iMessage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, thumbnails

I need a clickable thumbnail to indicate location, just like iMessage, what is the best way to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `MKMapView` to your table cell, but the better way to go would be to use `MKSnapshotter` to create snapshots and adding them to your cells instead.

From **NSHipster**'s blog post [here](http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/#MKMapsnapshotter), sample code to retrieve image from an `MKMapSnapshotter` is:

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.region = self.mapView.region;
options.size = self.mapView.frame.size;
options.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path/to/snapshot.png"];

MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
        return;
    }

    UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
}];
```

`options` passed to the snapshot here are `MKMapSnapshotOptions`. Read the  blog for more info and full tutorial.

`MKMapSnapshotter` is also flexible enough to add default/custom annotations to the snapshots, as you have posted in you question.

Sample code from the same source, with annotation is:

```
[snapshotter startWithQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
              completionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
      if (error) {
          NSLog(@"[Error] %@", error);
          return;
      }

      MKAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:nil reuseIdentifier:nil];

      UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, image.scale);
      {
          [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];

          CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
          for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
              CGPoint point = [snapshot pointForCoordinate:annotation.coordinate];
              if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)) {
                  point.x = point.x + pin.centerOffset.x -
                                (pin.bounds.size.width / 2.0f);
                  point.y = point.y + pin.centerOffset.y -
                                (pin.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
                  [pin.image drawAtPoint:point];
              }
          }

          UIImage *compositeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(compositeImage);
          [data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
      }
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}];
```

Tha catch here is, you will have to create an image from the snapshot with custom code.

Once the snapshot has been generated, you can plot it inside your cell.

If you want to optimize this further, you can save the generated snapshot in local storage, and use it on cell reuse for same coordinates, instead of generating an image each time the cell is reused.

Read the official documentation for `MKMapSnapshotter` [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotter_class/index.html), and `MKSnapshotOptions` [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotOptions_class/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, appreciate it!